# Fancybox 3 API - Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: javascript, prestashop, fancybox-3

i'm trying to load fancybox 3 to my prestashop product images using javascript from an external JS file,
but i get this error in my console : Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'open' of undefined.

i'v been testing this code on local and it works fine.

```
<a id="fancyboxlauncher" href="javascript:void(0)" >Click me</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('#fancyboxlauncher').on('click', function() {
'use strict';
  $.fancybox.open([
    {
      src  : '{$image.bySize.home_default.url}',
      opts : {
        caption : '{$product.description_short nofilter}'
      }
    }
  ], {
    loop : false,
    hash : "test"
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
{literal}
$('#fancyboxlauncher').on('click', function() {
'use strict';
  $.fancybox([
    {
      src  : "{/literal}{$image.bySize.home_default.url}{literal}",
      opts : {
        caption : "{/literal}{$product.description_short nofilter}{literal}"
      }
    }
  ], {
    loop : false,
    hash : "test"
  });
});
{/literal}
```

Comment: Don't think that it's the appropriate solution since i'm loading this code from an external JS file

Comment: how to use this on your external js file? you have used {$image} this smarty variable. smarty variable can not use on javascript file. Here i have seen you have use {$image} variable that why i have used {literal}.  may you can understand

Comment: for the {$image} i'll be changing that later on since i'm trying to load images dynamically
the main problem is that the js doesnt load proparly even after i added $.noConflict();
it starts loading but only onece, and than i get the same error in the conslole

Answer (score 0):

Quite obviously, the fancybox js file is not loaded, therefore `$.fancybox` is `undefined`and error message says `cannot read property 'open' of undefined`.

Edit: If you want to simply launch other group of images, you could do something like this:

```
$('#fancyboxlauncher').on('click', function() {
    $('[data-fancybox="quick-view"]').eq(0).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: actually when i use this code fancybox load automatically

    $.fancybox.open(
       {
          src  : 'http://www.artisanat-sf.com/artisanat-sans-frontieres-3/103-large_default/ballet.jpg',
        }
    );

Comment: What do you mean - "load automatically"? You are using some mechanism that loads JS files used by jQuery plugin on the demand? If so, then that is not working for you.

Comment: i mean that i'm loading this js in my front controller, if i dont use .on('click' ...
the JS will open automatically

Comment: Well, have you checked if fancybox has been loaded, e.g., "$.fancybox" is an object?

Comment: yes, the problem occures when i add $('#fancyboxlauncher').on('click', function() {});
to launch fancybox when i click on a link, again this scrip works fine when i test it in simple HTML file

Comment: The idea is to make fancybox skip the first image, since i have a large image and thmbnail in my product page, if i use class="quick_view" data-fancybox="quick-view", it will show a duplicate image